# Shorthand for set folder to variable if it exists or make new if it doesn't?

Tags: applescript

I know of

```
if folder "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop:thing" exists then
  set f to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop:thing
else
  set f to make new folder at "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop" with properties {name: "thing"}
end
```

and

```
try
    set f to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop:thing
on error
    set f to make new folder at "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop" with properties {name: "thing"}
end
```

Is there a shortcut? Of course, you could set the path to a variable, but that's still rather verbose. I don't quite understand the structure behind "commands" yet to even really know where or what to look for to figure out a better way. These pseudo-objective-oriented-but-really-querying structure is kinda baffling.

Comment: AppleScript doesn't have ternary operators like JavaScript and other languages, so it's hard to make an if/else statement more concise in AppleScript. mklement0's solution is about the cleanest you can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with filesystem items in AppleScript is notoriously quirky (Finder context vs. System Events context, HFS paths vs. POSIX paths).

I suggest:

- sticking with POSIX paths (with `/` as the root dir and path separator)
- using shell commands for convenience and brevity, via `do shell script`.

Here's a solution based on a generic helper function that accepts a POSIX folder path, creates the folder on demand, and returns the preexisting or just-created folder as an `alias` instance:

```applescript
on createAndOrGetFolder(posixPath)
    do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of posixPath
    return alias (posixPath as POSIX file)
end createAndOrGetFolder

set f to my createAndOrGetFolder(POSIX path of (path to desktop) & "thing")
```